# equivalent metrics yield bounds on metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a compact topological space with two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ inducing the same topology on $X$.

Problem. Show that if $\epsilon>0$ then there exists $\mu>0$ such that if $d_1(x,y)<\epsilon$ then $d_2(x,y)<\mu$

Attempt:

I'm trying to use that for each $r>0$ and any $x\in X$ there exists $\epsilon_1>0$ and $\epsilon_2>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon_1}^{(d_1)}(x)\subseteq B_r^{(d_2)}(x)$   and $B_{\epsilon_2}^{d_2}(x)\subseteq B_r^{(d_1)}(x)$.

But I don't know where to use compactness

Alternatively, $id:(X,d_1)\rightarrow (X,d_2)$ is uniformly continuous.

So, if $\epsilon>0$ then there exists a $\delta$ such that if $d_1(x,y)<\delta$ then $d_2(x,y)<\epsilon$.

But this has constants other way around

Comment: The question still doesn't seem to make sense: a metric inducing a compact topology on a set is bounded: your $\mu$  doesn't depend on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry, this was a problem gven in lectures. Not my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A metric on a set $X$ is a continuous function from $X \times X$ to $\Bbb{R}$. A product of compact sets is compact and a  continuous image of a compact set is compact. So your metric $d_2$ maps $X \times X$ to a compact and hence bounded subset of $\Bbb{R}$. You can now take $\mu$ to any upper bound for that set,